# How to properly calculate month difference on typescript dates Angular

Tags: typescript, date

First off: I'm working on Angular 7.

Let's say I have a number X, e.g. a rate I have to pay every month. So on given two dates `startDate` and `endDate` I want to calculate how much I gotta pay for this given timespan. Maybe a more tensible example:

Let's assume my rate is `10.00`

My `startDate` is `2018-12-01` and my `endDate` is `2018-12-31`, I need to calculate `1 * 10.00 = 10.00`.
While doing this, I'm going to assume that I do only look at "full month", so an `endDate` of `2018-12-13` could not be entered, just `2018-12-31`, `2019-01-31` or `2019-02-28` (or ofc. `2019-02-29`).

I could not make it work (sadly), so I looked around and got stuck at this method:

```
  monthDiff(d1: Date, d2: Date): number {
    let months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
  }
```

This does (sadly) also not work out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend moment.js to work with dates.
See the link: https://momentjs.com/

I think it's the most used js library to work with dates nowadays.
Have a look at it, you'll see it is easy to use.

I wish that help.

Thank you!